# New Tire or Used Tire

Tags: tires

This is my first question here, and so if this question belongs somewhere else, please let me know.

In July, I got a flat and bought a new tire. The tire cost just over 100 dollars (including the labor). It has no hubcap. I haven't really thought about it, but this week the tire pressure light went on in my car and it was only that tire that needed air. It is the rear driver side tire. Is this a sign that the tire was bought used? The auto shop where I bought the tire (an established chain) did not mention anything about it being used.

In addition, the shop did not replace the spare where it belongs under the car after putting in the new tire. Is this a reasonable complaint?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If the tyre shop had a slack approach they might not have properly inflated the tyre, so even a small loss of air would cause the sensor to flag it. The way to see if there is a puncture is to get the tyre examined. And/or to see how soon the pressure is flagged again after inflating to the correct pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good used tire should hold air just as well as a new tire, so no it isn’t an indication that it is used.

Possibilities -

- You have got another puncture, which isn’t impossible.
- The original tire didn’t have a puncture, but had a problem sealing on a corroded rim.  The new tire is also having the same issue.
- The original tire had a puncture, but the rim also has some corrosion that is now not sealing the new tire correctly.
- It is a used tire that had a very small puncture.  I think that it is very very unlikely to have stayed inflated for all that time.

Just go back and get then to check why it has gone down.  The rim may need a refurb.  Often on old wheels, they will do there best to clean corrosion off the inside of the rim before fitting a new tire.  Maybe yours is in bad condition.

Did you ask them to put the spare back in the rack?  If your flat tire was in the boot/trunk when you took it to them, maybe they just left it the same way without your instruction.

Comment: The spare was on the car, being used as a tire when I took it to them. And based on this information, you would not know if it was used or new, correct?

Comment: I realise the spare was being used when you took it to them, but had you put the flat tire back in the rack, or was it in the trunk?  I would have though looking at the tire when you got it you would be able to see clearly that it had never been on the road.  Now, after a few months of use you probably wouldn’t be able to tell the difference, other than it should still have a very deep tread.

Comment: Thanks. I hear what you are saying about where the flat was. It was in the trunk, so I suppose that makes some more sense.